# : Optimal Batch Size for Predicting Large Number of Abstracts with SciBERT?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I'm currently employing SciBERT to classify the categories of scientific abstracts. My dataset comprises approximately 5 million abstracts, and each abstract contains, on average, around 200 tokens.

In my initial attempts, I experimented with larger batch sizes such as 10k, 20k, etc., but observed varying results for each case.

Can anyone provide insights or recommendations on the optimal batch size to efficiently and quickly predict these abstracts using SciBERT?

code snippet:

```
# Define batch size
batch_size = 10000

# Make batch predictions
for start_idx in range(0, len(df_testAbstract_Text1), batch_size):
    end_idx = start_idx + batch_size
    batch_data = df_testAbstract_Text1[start_idx:end_idx]
    predictions, raw_outputs = model.predict(list(batch_data))
    all_predictions.extend(predictions)
    all_raw_outputs.extend(raw_outputs)
```